# Loop that changes letter colors

Tags: javascript

The purpose is to change color of all characters in #text one by one, I made a loop:

```
function myFunction() {
        var letters = document.getElementById('text');
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.innerHTML.length; i++) {
            //only change the one you want to
                letters.innerHTML = letters.innerHTML.replace(letters[i], '<span style="color: yellow;">'+letters[i]+'</span>');
           }
    }
```

It doesnt work but also doesnt show any errors.

https://jsfiddle.net/zkbctk2h/

Comment: If you put `console.log(letters[i])` in your for loop, you will see you get 206 `undefined`s being logged. That tells you `letters` is not an array of letters (it's a `div`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to store the text of the element with `id = "text"` and build a new string out of the old text, because replace would replace the first found character which may not the wanted character, because the replaced character cold contain a character which should not be replaced.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var letters = document.getElementById('text'),
        text = letters.innerHTML
      
    letters.innerHTML = '';    
    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        letters.innerHTML += '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + text[i] + '</span>';
    }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="text">abracadabra</div>
```

Some typewriter functionality with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var letters = document.getElementById('text'),
        text = letters.innerHTML,
        i = 0;
      
    return function () {
        var j;
        if (i < text.length) {
            letters.innerHTML = '';
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                letters.innerHTML += '<span style="background-color: yellow;">' + text[j] + '</span>';
            }
            letters.innerHTML += text.slice(j);
            i++;
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
}

var interval = setInterval(myFunction(), 500);
```

```html
<div id="text">abracadabra</div>
```

Comment: Works brilliant,  is it possible to 'slow down' that loop? To make it slowly change background of letters one by one?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are updating the letters, and reading the next letter afterwards. You should use innerText instead of innerHTML because then you only get the text.

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zkbctk2h/25/

```
function myFunction() {
    var letters = document.getElementById('text'),
        str = letters.innerText,
        newString = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        //only change the one you want to
            newString += '<span style="color: yellow;">'+str[i]+'</span>';
       }

    letters.innerHTML = newString;
}
```

I suggest to read once and write once to the dom. If you read and write a force redraw is triggered in the browser. Therefor it can get slow if you have large text.

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting a more functional approach:

```js
const myFunction = id =>
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML
    .split('')
    .map(c =>
      `<span style="color: green;">${c}</span>`
    )
    .join('')

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = myFunction('text')
```

```html
<div id="text">Hello World</div>
```